# Trying to dynamically change the text in a text-area inside a onkeypress event

Tags: javascript

OK I want to change what is in the text area using substrings and what not. JavaScript does not seem to let me do it. I have two text areas one can be changed based off of what is inside the text area and also what key is being pressed. However the text area I am typing into will not change during the the onkeypress event. What do i do to make it so that as you type what you type can be change triggered by a onkeypress event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function textchange() {
      switch (event.keyCode) {
          case 13: enterbutton();
              break;
          case 32: return spacebutton();
          default: break;

      }

      function enterbutton() {

      }
      function spacebutton() {
          var t1 = document.getElementById('TextArea1');
          var t2 = document.getElementById('TextArea2');
          t2.innerHTML = t2.innerHTML + 'yay ';
          t1.innerHTML = t1.innerHTML + '-yay-';  // t1. where im typing.. not changing
         return false;
      }

  //    alert(event.keyCode);
  }

 </script>
```

Comment: <p>
<textarea id="TextArea1" cols="80" rows="25"  onkeypress="return textchange(event);"></textarea>
        <br />
        <textarea id="TextArea2" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea>
</p>

Comment: edit your question to contain the code, click `edit` near the bottom of your question, comments are not a good place for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong thing in trying to set the value of the textarea. Input type elements(input,textarea,select) you use `.value` to get/set their value

```
function spacebutton() {
   var t1 = document.getElementById('TextArea1');
   var t2 = document.getElementById('TextArea2');
   t2.value = t2.value + 'yay ';
   t1.value = t1.value + '-yay-';
}
```

Comment: .value also works but it still does not change the text in the text-area in which I am typing.

Comment: oops, dont return false, returning false will make the default behavior from happening and will not update the textarea.